# Error with applying data type in method to variables in main tester class

Tags: java, arrays, methods, statistics

How can I get this to calculate properties about arrays of doubles. If everything else is an int inside, would that still as an array of doubles? Or is it still an array of doubles anyway because of the method type? Here is my class. Thanks so much!

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Math;

public class Statistics {
    private double min;
    private double max;
    private double mean;
    private double median;
    private double deviation;
    private double mode;

public static double findMin(int[] array){
         int min = array[0];  
         for(int i=1;i<array.length;i++){  
         if(array[i] < min){  
         min = array[i];  
            }  
         }  
        return min;  

    }

public static double findMax(int[] array){
        int max = array[0];
        for(int i=1;i<array.length;i++){
            if(array[i]>max){
                max=array[i];
            }
        }
        return max;

    }

public static double calcMean(int[] n){
    int sum=0;
    for (int i=0; i<n.length; i++){
        sum+= n[i];
    }
    return sum/n.length;
}

public static double calcMedian(int[] n){
    int middle = n.length/2;
    if (n.length%2==1){
        return n[middle];
    } else {
        return (n[middle]+n[middle])/2;
    }
}

public static double calcDeviation(int[] n){
    int mean = (int)calcMean(n);
    int squareSum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
    squareSum += Math.pow(n[i] - mean, 2);
    }   
    return Math.sqrt((squareSum) / (n.length - 1));

}

public static double calcMode(int n[]){
    int value=0; int max=0;

    for (int i=0;i<n.length;++i){
        int count=0;
        for (int j=0; j<n.length; ++j){
            if (n[j]==n[i]) ++count;
        }
        if (count>max){
            max=count;
            value=n[i];

        }
    }

    return value;
}


}
```

Here is my main method.

```
import java.util.*;

public class StatisticsTester {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    Statistics test = new Statistics();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    //Read user  input.
    System.out.print("How many numbers do you want to enter?: ");
    int num = input.nextInt();
    double array[] = new double[num];
    System.out.println("Enter the " + num + "numbers now.");
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++ )
    {
        array[i] = input.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.print("Here is the minimum, ");
    System.out.print("maximum, mean, median, ");
    System.out.println("mode, and standard deviation: ");
    System.out.print(test.findMin(num) +", " + test.findMax(num));
    System.out.print(", "+ test.calcMean(num) +", ");
    System.out.print(test.calcMedian(num) +", ");
    System.out.print(test.calcMode(num) +", ");
    System.out.print(test.calcDeviation(num));

}
}
```

These are the errors when it compiles.

```
StatisticsTester.java:25: findMin(int[]) in Statistics cannot be applied to (int)
    System.out.print(test.findMin(num) +", " + test.findMax(num));
                         ^
StatisticsTester.java:25: findMax(int[]) in Statistics cannot be applied to (int)
    System.out.print(test.findMin(num) +", " + test.findMax(num));
                                                   ^
StatisticsTester.java:26: calcMean(int[]) in Statistics cannot be applied to (int)
    System.out.print(", "+ test.calcMean(num) +", ");
                               ^
StatisticsTester.java:27: calcMedian(int[]) in Statistics cannot be applied to (int)
    System.out.print(test.calcMedian(num) +", ");
                         ^
StatisticsTester.java:28: calcMode(int[]) in Statistics cannot be applied to (int)
    System.out.print(test.calcMode(num) +", ");
                         ^
StatisticsTester.java:29: calcDeviation(int[]) in Statistics cannot be applied to (int)
    System.out.print(test.calcDeviation(num));
                         ^
6 errors
```

Comment: You're passing in an integer to a method which only accepts an array. Don't do that.

Comment: Looks like you typo'd your argument. You prob want to use `array` instead of `num`

Comment: Your methods all take `int[]`s. You have a `double[]`, so you can't pass it to any of those methods, because it's not an `int[]`.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Is it true that arrays only take ints? I tried to do it with doubles in my methods and the rest of the arguments using doubles. It didn't work. I got all "possible loss of precision" errors.

Comment: @Lorber Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Does anyone know how I can use doubles in my arguments for all of this or as much of this that will still work? Or is it honestly not possible?  

I have tried converting all the ints in my Statistics class file multiple times over to double and tried to let some be ints as well. It never works, they all always have to be ints. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two errors :

First : When you do this - `test.findMin(num)` you are trying to pass parameter num. But num is not array! It is a number. You probably want to do this : `test.findMin(array)`

Second : You can implicitly convert integer to double, because you can be sure that it remains same. But you cant convert double to integer implicitly, because you cant convert for example 2,7 to integer. And for arrays, even the "implicit" conversion does not work.

---

Solution for you, change this line `double array[] = new double[num];` to `int array[] = new int[num];` and then change all your parameters which looks like this `test.findMin(num)` to this `test.findMin(array)`

---

For working with doubles this would compile (does not know if it works as expected) :

```
import java.util.*;

public class StatisticsTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Statistics test = new Statistics();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        //Read user  input.
        System.out.print("How many numbers do you want to enter?: ");
        int num = input.nextInt();
        double array[] = new double[num];
        System.out.println("Enter the " + num + "numbers now.");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = input.nextDouble();
        }
        System.out.print("Here is the minimum, ");
        System.out.print("maximum, mean, median, ");
        System.out.println("mode, and standard deviation: ");
        System.out.print(test.findMin(array) + ", " + test.findMax(array));
        System.out.print(", " + test.calcMean(array) + ", ");
        System.out.print(test.calcMedian(array) + ", ");
        System.out.print(test.calcMode(array) + ", ");
        System.out.print(test.calcDeviation(array));

    }
}
```

---

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Math;

public class Statistics {

    private double min;
    private double max;
    private double mean;
    private double median;
    private double deviation;
    private double mode;

    public static double findMin(double[] array) {
        double min = array[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] < min) {
                min = array[i];
            }
        }
        return min;

    }

    public static double findMax(double[] array) {
        double max = array[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] > max) {
                max = array[i];
            }
        }
        return max;

    }

    public static double calcMean(double[] n) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
            sum += n[i];
        }
        return sum / n.length;
    }

    public static double calcMedian(double[] n) {
        int middle = n.length / 2;
        if (n.length % 2 == 1) {
            return n[middle];
        } else {
            return (n[middle] + n[middle]) / 2;
        }
    }

    public static double calcDeviation(double[] n) {
        int mean = (int) calcMean(n);
        int squareSum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
            squareSum += Math.pow(n[i] - mean, 2);
        }
        return Math.sqrt((squareSum) / (n.length - 1));

    }

    public static double calcMode(double n[]) {
        double value = 0;
        int max = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < n.length; ++i) {
            int count = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < n.length; ++j) {
                if (n[j] == n[i]) {
                    ++count;
                }
            }
            if (count > max) {
                max = count;
                value = n[i];

            }
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, @libik !

I tried all your changes but I still have these errors. 

    StatisticsTester.java:16: possible loss of precision
    found   : double
    required: int
              int array[] = new int[num];
                                    ^
    StatisticsTester.java:20: possible loss of precision
    found   : double
    required: int
                            array[i] = input.nextDouble();

Comment: @Lorber - looks like you have  `input.nextDouble()` there, just change it to `input.nextInt()` (just change every double you have to int)

Comment: Okay I changed it. It all works now, you are fantastic, but is this considered an array of doubles even though I can only enter ints? Or does array of doubles only mean what this will be calculated to and not necessarily the numbers I can enter in the array?

Comment: If something is type of double, everything you put in, is saved as double and it is computed as double. There is no memory of "how I got this number" or "is this double also integer?". So even if you "know" you cannot put any non-integer into double variable, the compiler does not know that.

Comment: I appreciate your responses, libik. After I made your edits and I am asked for the numbers I wish to enter, if I type in a double, I get this error result. 

Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:840)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1461)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2091)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2050)
 at StatisticsTester.main(StatisticsTester.java:20)

Does that not imply there is a memory or preference?

Comment: @Lorber - it is expected behaviour, you are calling "nextInt()" method, so you are expecting to get int. If someone put there a non-integer value, you  cannot return it as an integer, so it throws an exception.

Comment: @Lorber - but it is all discovered in that moment it "works with it". If it saves the value into array somehow, once it saved there, you are not able to find, "how it got there".

Comment: You are right. My goal is to use doubles though and for some reason, I am unable to use double variables in any of this. Do you know what I can do to make this use doubles and work? Thanks again!

Comment: @Lorber - if you want to use a double change almost every int into double, it will work :). But if you want to do that, there was no reason to create methods which accepts integer array values, if you want to do something with doubles.

Comment: @Lorber - You just have to think where you need the integer (which is a whole number) and where you want to do something with double (which is not just a whole number).

Also remember that double and float are not always precise! So work with it as long as you do not expect always exact values.

Comment: I changed every int to a double in the Statistics class before I even made the StatisticsTester.java file and for every double I assigned outside of the method name, it would give me a "possible loss of precision" error. Is the double array value typed differently? I am very appreciative of your help!

Comment: Whoa, you're a god! How do I give you infinite comments or upvotes?

Comment: @Lorber - you can Accept this answer, it is good enough ;). (it is button somewhere near the up and downvote)